# How many bathrooms can be connected on a 3 inch vertical stack?

Tags: plumbing, pvc

How many bathrooms can be connected on a 3 inch vertical stack?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Referring to the International Plumbing Code, a bathroom group requires 5 Drainage Fixture Units.

As a horizontal branch 3" is good for 20 DFU's or 4 bathroom groups.

In vertical stacks the number goes up with multiple branches but each single branch is limited to 20 DFU's

Good Luck and check the tables here:

https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018/chapter-9-vents

Answer (score -3):

There are important criteria to remember when sizing a conventional venting system
composed of individual fixture vents, vent stacks, and stack vents. The minimum size of an
individual vent is one-half the required drain size, whereas the minimum size of the vent
stacks and stack vents is one-half the size of the drain served.

Comment: While inherently true, this adds nothing to the answer that was posted 3 years ago. Care to [edit] to add more detail and something new and previously unstated?